# Virtual Host for RoundCube

Tags: ubuntu, email-server, ubuntu-10.04, webmail, roundcube

i have RoundCube setup on a ubuntu 10.04 server, and it works perfectly when browsing to address.tld/roundcube

however I would like to be able to go to mail.address.tld

for this I have added the following virtual host config:

```
<VirtualHost mail.address.tld>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName mail.address.tld/roundcube
DocumentRoot /var/www/roundcube
<Directory /var/www/roundcube>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/roundcube>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

The Roundcube page is able to open however the PHP functions do not work correctly. I would like to resolve that.

Comment: Provide some details, what functions are not working ? What error messages are you getting ?

Comment: The functions that are not working are things like reading mail and basicly anything dynamic on the page. replying, deleting forwarding and viewing messages in the viewing pane.

Comment: what version of roundcube are you running? 0.3 stable? 0.4 beta? or the one that came with Ubuntu 10.04 (which is buggy)?

Comment: I am using the version from Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

I allowed symlinks in Apache

Then modified the the symlinks to point to the full path of of the javescript file.
By default it was using a relative path.

```
ln -s /usr/share/javascript/jquery/jquery.min.js jquery-1.3.min.js
```

Thank for the help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the ServerName line is wrong. Just delete the "/roundcube" at the end.

Please use the following and tell us, what your findings in /var/log/yourdomain.error.log are.

```
<VirtualHost mail.address.tld>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost 
  ServerName mail.address.tld 
  DocumentRoot /var/www/roundcube 
  ErrorLog /var/log/yourdomain.error.log 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I made this change however the problem is still occurring. Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you create a DNS entry for mail.address.tld?

Comment: Yes I did, and the page does resolve correctly.

Comment: Added an alternate definition to the answer.

Comment: Here is a section of the logs:

[Tue Jul 27 13:16:14 2010] [error] [client 64.91.77.185] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/roundcube/program/js/jquery-1.3.min.js, referer: http://mail.domain.tld/
[Tue Jul 27 13:16:19 2010] [error] [client 64.91.77.185] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/roundcube/program/js/jquery-1.3.min.js, referer: http://mail.domain.tld/?_task=mail&_mbox=INBOX